# JavaScript: Using Reduce Method to Merge Together Multiple Arrays Into One Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

I have the following code below:

```
const intersection = (arr) => {

  //console.log(arr)

  return arr.reduce((a,e) => a+e, [])

}

const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3]));
```

I am expecting my code to print `[5,10,15,2015,88,1,5,71,10,15,5,20]` but instead it's printing `5,10,15,2015,88,1,5,71,10,15,5,20`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to apply the `+` operator to arrays, which javascript doesn't support. Use `concat` instead: `(a,e) => a.concat(e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to combine the arrays with the `+` operator. Since arrays don't support the `+` operator, they are casted to strings. You can use array spread or `Array.concat()` to combine them using `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const intersection = arr => arr.reduce((a, e) => [...a, ...e], [])

const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3]));
```

Or you can use `Array.flat()`:

```js
const intersection = arr => arr.flat();

const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `+` to add arrays. Use `concat` instead:

```js
const intersection = arr => arr.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e), []);

const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```